# Combining two queries on same table

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've looked through several previous questions but I am struggling to apply the solutions to my specific example.

I am having trouble combining query 1 and query 2.

My query originally returned (amongst other details) the values "*SpentTotal*" and "*UnderSpent*" for all members/users for the **current** month.

My issue has been adding two additional columns to this original quert that will return JUST these two columns (Spent and Overspent) but for the **previous** months data

Original Query #1:

```
set @BPlanKey = '##CURRENTMONTH##'
EXECUTE @RC = Minimum_UpdateForPeriod @BPlanKey

SELECT cm.clubaccountnumber, bp.Description , msh.PeriodMinObligation,  msh.SpentTotal, msh.UnderSpent, msh.OverSpent, msh.BilledDate, msh.PeriodStartDate, msh.PeriodEndDate, msh.OverSpent 
FROM MinimumSpendHistory msh 
     INNER JOIN BillPlanMinimums bpm ON msh.BillingPeriodKey = @BPlanKey and bpm.BillPlanMinimumKey = msh.BillPlanMinimumKey 
     INNER JOIN BillPlans bp ON bp.BillPlanKey = bpm.BillPlanKey 
     INNER JOIN ClubMembers cm ON cm.parentmemberkey is null and cm.ClubMemberKey = msh.ClubMemberKey 
order by cm.clubaccountnumber asc, msh.BilledDate asc
```

Query #2, query of all columns for PREVIOUS month, but I only need two (spent and over spent), added to the query from above, joined on the customer number:

```
set @BPlanKeyLastMo = '##PREVMONTH##'
EXECUTE @RCLastMo = Minimum_UpdateForPeriod @BPlanKeyLastMo

SELECT cm.clubaccountnumber, bp.Description , msh.PeriodMinObligation, msh.SpentTotal, msh.UnderSpent, msh.OverSpent, msh.BilledDate, msh.PeriodStartDate, msh.PeriodEndDate, msh.OverSpent 
FROM MinimumSpendHistory msh 
     INNER JOIN BillPlanMinimums bpm ON msh.BillingPeriodKey = @BPlanKeyLastMo and bpm.BillPlanMinimumKey = msh.BillPlanMinimumKey 
     INNER JOIN BillPlans bp ON bp.BillPlanKey = bpm.BillPlanKey 
     INNER JOIN ClubMembers cm ON cm.parentmemberkey is null and cm.ClubMemberKey = msh.ClubMemberKey 
order by cm.clubaccountnumber asc, msh.BilledDate asc
```

Big thank you to any and all that are willing to lend their help and time.

Cheers!

- AJ

---

```
CREATE TABLE MinimumSpendHistory(
        [MinimumSpendHistoryKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [BillPlanMinimumKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [ClubMemberKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [BillingPeriodKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [PeriodStartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [PeriodEndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [PeriodMinObligation] [money] NOT NULL,
        [SpentTotal] [money] NOT NULL,
        [CurrentSpent] [money] NOT NULL,
        [OverSpent] [money] NULL,
        [UnderSpent] [money] NULL,
        [BilledAmount] [money] NOT NULL,
        [BilledDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [PriorPeriodMinimum] [money] NULL,
        [IsCommitted] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [IsCalculated] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [BillPeriodMinimumKey] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [CarryForwardCounter] [smallint] NULL,
        [YTDSpent] [money] NOT NULL,
        [PeriodToAccumulateCounter] [int] NULL,
        [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Table definitions would be useful.

Comment: I don't see any subqueries in your code. Is this code itself the subquery?

Comment: table definitions include things like primary keys and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are almost certainly more straightforward ways of doing it, but this will probably work:

If ClubAccountNumber isn't unique on ClubMembers you'll need to select the primary key of this table too and join the two subselects on that instead.

```
Select
  a.ClubAccountNumber, 
  a.Description,
  a.PeriodMinObligation,
  a.SpentTotal,
  a.UnderSpent, 
  a.OverSpent, 
  a.BilledDate, 
  a.PeriodStartDate, 
  a.PeriodEndDate, 
  a.OverSpent, -- this second instance of overspent is from the question...
  b.SpentTotal As LastMonthSpentTotal, 
  b.UnderSpent As LastMonthUnderspent
From (
  Select
    cm.ClubAccountNumber, 
    bp.Description,
    msh.PeriodMinObligation,
    msh.SpentTotal,
    msh.UnderSpent, 
    msh.OverSpent, 
    msh.BilledDate, 
    msh.PeriodStartDate, 
    msh.PeriodEndDate
  From
    MinimumSpendHistory msh 
      Inner Join
    BillPlanMinimums bpm 
      On msh.BillingPeriodKey = @BPlanKey And bpm.BillPlanMinimumKey = msh.BillPlanMinimumKey 
      Inner Join
    BillPlans bp 
      On bp.BillPlanKey = bpm.BillPlanKey
      Inner Join
    ClubMembers cm 
      On cm.ParentMemberKey Is Null And cm.ClubMemberKey = msh.ClubMemberKey 
  ) a Left Outer Join (
  Select 
    cm.ClubAccountNumber,
    msh.SpentTotal,
    msh.UnderSpent
  From
    MinimumSpendHistory msh 
      Inner Join
    BillPlanMinimums bpm 
      On msh.BillingPeriodKey = @BPlanKeyLastMo and bpm.BillPlanMinimumKey = msh.BillPlanMinimumKey
      Inner Join
    BillPlans bp 
      On bp.BillPlanKey = bpm.BillPlanKey 
      Inner Join
    ClubMembers cm 
      On cm.ParentMemberKey Is Null And cm.ClubMemberKey = msh.ClubMemberKey 
  ) b On a.ClubAccountNumber = b.ClubAccountNumber -- this should probably join on cm.clubmemberkey, but we are guessing
Order By
  a.ClubAccountNumber, 
  a.BilledDate
```

Comment: Im getting an "incorrect syntax near [the first] FROM." When I hover over the "a" in ") a Left Outer Join (" it reads --the column 'OverSpent' was specified multiple times for a --  I thought it was related to the two instances of a.OverSpent at the top, but it was not.

Comment: @user1830856 didn't notice you'd selected the same value twice, fixed that.

Comment: still receiving the "incorrect syntax near from" on the FIRST from. so  close! I appreciate your help.

Comment: I noticed another typo, if you want to try again.

Comment: was in the middle of setting up those tables when i saw your update.  pasted it into SQL2008 and the syntax looks good. about to test it out now, update to come after i get it implemented! (soon)

Comment: Blam's solution is shorter, and I think it will return the same thing (unless people can have bill plans in the msh table that don't exist in the parent tables).

Comment: After testing both queries THIS version produced the results I was anticipating.  The solution from Blam was also successful, but included duplicates of the ClubAccountNumber.  Thank you both (and everyone else) for help!  Many Mahalos.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cm.clubaccountnumber, bp.Description , msh.PeriodMinObligation,  msh.SpentTotal, msh.UnderSpent, msh.OverSpent, msh.BilledDate, msh.PeriodStartDate, msh.PeriodEndDate, 
mshp.SpentTotal, mshp.UnderSpent
FROM MinimumSpendHistory msh 
     INNER JOIN BillPlanMinimums bpm ON msh.BillingPeriodKey = @BPlanKey 
                                    and bpm.BillPlanMinimumKey = msh.BillPlanMinimumKey 
     INNER JOIN BillPlans bp ON bp.BillPlanKey = bpm.BillPlanKey 
     INNER JOIN ClubMembers cm ON cm.parentmemberkey is null 
                              and cm.ClubMemberKey = msh.ClubMemberKey
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ClubMembers cmp on cm.ClubMemberKey = msh.ClubMemberKey
     LEFT OUTER JOIN MinimumSpendHistory mshp on cmp.ClubMemberKey = mshp.ClubMemberKey
                              and mshp mshp.BillingPeriodKey = @BPlanKeyLastMo
order by cm.clubaccountnumber asc, msh.BilledDate asc
```

Comment: If you want to go down that route then each MinimumSpendHistory row could have different BillPlanMinimums and BillPlan rows. Plus there might not be any previous months data.

Comment: I look him at a literal on joined on the customer number.

Comment: I wrote it all out joining on the other tables again, and now I think you're right.